# how can I make nested loop for this code?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

How can I reform my code and make nested for loop?

```
for i in range (1,5):
    print (i,end = " ")
print()

for j in range (5,9):
    print (j , end = " ")
```

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 5 6 7 8

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why and how do you intend to nest?

Comment: Please, provide input and output.

Answer (score 0):

What type of output are looking to have?

Generally to nest a loop simply put it under the first.

```
for outer in range(10):
    print(outer)
    for inner in range(5):
        print(inner)
```

Comment: 1 2 3 4
#new row
5 6 7 8

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want a nested loop. A nested loop would yield something sort of cartesian like. 

      1 5678
      2 5678 # etc

if you just want a row of 1234 followed by 5678 then what you have works short of some weirdness with the end. 

What I would do here is: 

      print(*range(1,5), sep=" ")
      print(*range(5, 9), sep= " ")

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as:

```
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in range(1,5)]))
```